# Browser tab icon is not showing up

Tags: html

I am making a website and there is an error.
It won't show the website icon.
Proof: https://i.stack.imgur.com/053Xh.png
Code:

```html
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon32.ico" type="image/x-icon"
```

Comment: Clear your browser `cache` that might help.

Comment: It may be caused by: 1) the tag is not completed. 2) the file path of icon is wrong, check console. 3) Clear browser's cache and check again.

Answer (score -1):

You are not closing the link tag add this " /> " at the end

```
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon32.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

**Do the following things.**

1. Please close you link tag by adding "/>"
2. For good practice, first move favicon in main/root folder, not in inner   folders, to load it fast
3. Change your favicon file name into "favicon" and its extension must
   be "ico" not icon. Please see the file name carefully.

Comment: @bacionBOl, Try this: please remove 32 from filename from link.